# Referential Relationship - Deleting Parent Cause Update Plugin to fire on Children

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have Entity A and has a 1:N referntial relationship to Entity B. I have a Delete Plugin regietered on Entity A and Update Plugin registered on Entity B. When I delete Entity A, the Update plugin on Entity B fires and throw an exception saying: 
 **Error in  updatePlugIn: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: EntityA With Id = 26c7cccc-6a93-e311-b537-005056836fb7 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).**

When I delete EntityA is there anything changing on EntityB causing the update plugin to fire? Please NOTE that the relationship between the 2 entities is REFERENTIAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be removing the link to entity A on entity B which will fire the update plugin if it is set to look at all attributes or that attribute is in the list.

To get around this you could change the update plugin step to only fire on the change of certain attributes and/or make your plugin code check for entity A before running.